# Display short block inline center

Tags: html, css

How do I center the "Brainy Quote" on the top center of a page. Here is a print screen of what it currently looks like.

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to get it to look like.

[image]

When I tried using text-align center it causes the entire line to be blue.

```css
#link {
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">
    Turns out you have a really fun time if you go to work every day and focus on being silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
  </div>
  <p id="link">
    <a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
    Brainy Quote
    </a>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried margin: 1em auto;        Also can you show us your HTML?

Comment: can you share your html as well?

Comment: Can u post html code also?

Comment: Check the answer, it is edited now.

Answer (score 0):

For your absolute element, you can do :

```
.thing-to-center {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. I have added an extra div tag and aligned the content center. Also in the link ID, position is absolute.

When compared to given picture, some of the css details are missing in the other 4 boxes.

```css
#link {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: BLACK;
  text-align: center;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

#contain {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">
    Turns out you have a really fun time if you go to work every day and focus on being silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
  </div>

  <div id="contain">
    <p id="link">
      <a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
Brainy Quote
</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`left` and `right` attributes only work with `relative` and `absolute` positioned elements. Add `position:relative;` to your `#link`

```css
#link {
  position: relative; /* Or `absolute` */
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">
    Turns out you have a really fun time if you go to work every day and focus on being silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
  </div>
  <p id="link">
    <a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
    Brainy Quote
    </a>
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed, you have used block for quotes and give "fixed" position.
Now you have to set link, use this

```
#link {
    text-align: center;
}
```

It will set the link on top at the center